# generating javascript array from php

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm loosing hairs on this.

I have an PHP array:

```
Array
(
    [10-10-2015] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [hour] => 10:00
                    [title] => Meeting x
                )

        )

    [10-09-2015] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [hour] => 17:00
                    [title] => another meeting
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [hour] => 11:11
                    [title] => other meeting
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see, there are two meetings in the same day.
That's correct.

I need to generate Javascript array:

```
var codropsEvents = {
    '10-16-2015': ['<span>event one</span>', '<span>event two</span>'],
    '10-17-2015': ['<span>event one</span>', '<span>event two</span>'],
};
```

Any help or suggestions how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New progress...

Without JSON.parse, only just:

```
var codropsEvents = <?=json_encode($events);?>
```

it's returning

```
var codropsEvents = {
    "10-10-2015":[
                     {"time":"10:00","title":"Meeting X"}
                 ],
    "10-09-2015":[
                     {"time":"17:00","title":"Other event"},
                     {"time":"11:11","title":"Other Meeting"}
                 ]
 }
```

which causes returning Object

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode($array)` in php to convert it to valid json string. In your javascript you can use `JSON.parse(json)` for parsing json string.

For example :

```
<?php
$array=array
(
    '10-10-2015' => array
        (
            0 => array
                (
                    'hour' => '10:00',
                    'title' => 'Meeting x'
                )

        )
);
?>

<script>

var data = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>');
// or var data = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json.

```
echo 'var myJsArray = JSON.parse("'.json_encode($myPhpArray).'");';
```

Comment: JSON is itself valid JavaScript Object Notation. You don't have to parse it again if you're going to inline it as in your example.

Comment: @AlfredoDelgado, yes I agree with this fact, but when php encodes it to json it escapes it and converts unicode characters and etc. So that's why have to parse it.

Comment: Something else worth noting: the `json_encode` output from the sample PHP array will result in a JavaScript `Object()`, not an `Array()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

create array that You want:

```
<?php

  $events = .....;

  $data = [];
  foreach($events AS $date => $eventsByDate) {
      $data[$date] = [];
      foreach($eventsByDate AS $event) {
          $data[$date][] = '<span>'.$event['title'].'</span>';
      }
  }

?>
```

output $data array encoded as json string and parse it to get javascript object or array:

```
<script>
var codropsEvents = JSON.parse('<?=json_encode($data)?>');
console.log(codropsEvents);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting error SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

var codropsEvents = JSON.parse("{"":["

The other option is formatting in different way PHP Array. I also generating it so the structure of array can be different